# Error in Google cloud speech plugin with unity

Tags: plugins, google-api, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-speech

I downloaded the plugin from the store but when I try it I get error.. It worked only when I say hello any other word with any language does not work. This is the error I get
[enter this link to find the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrGRX.png)

I use windows 10 , unity 5, and this google plugin is the latest one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I did not know that google cloud needs network connection so the problem solved when I connected it.